# Update Django server after creating thumbnail with AWS Lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a Django web project that is using Amazon S3 for media files.  The file upload is happening async direct from the browser.

I need to create some thumbnail images for each file that is uploaded.  I found a [tutorial for how to do this using AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) (which I've never used before) but seems like the future of web.

The only issue I am trying to figure out in my head is: how I will update my database back on the django web server with the information for the newly created thumbnail images?  I intend to create a new database model (`thumbnails`) that will store the URL and tie the thumbmail to the main image information.

The only thing I have come up with is to expose a url on my web app to accept HTTP requests (assuming lambda can send HTTP requests).  So when the lambda function completes a thumbnail image, it will send the request to my web app with the information for the newly created thumbnail image using POST or PUT.

The thing I don't like about this approach is that it won't work when developing locally.  Does anyone have any experience using Lambda to create thumbnails and then communicating back with your web server which differs from my proposed plan?

Comment: The Lambda function could send a message to SQS, and your webapp would poll SQS.

Comment: For thumbnails, I would do a one-way trip to AWS.  I send AWS the original, named "img-0001.jpg" and Lambda would make a thumbnail and append "-thumbnail" to the name, ending up with "img-0001-thumbnail.jpg".  Back in Django, without any feedback from AWS, I already know my thumbnail name will be "img-0001-thumbnail.jpg" and I put that in the database.